# Can we rewrite a sum product without the summation notation?

Tags: linear-algebra, summation, notation

More specifically, is there a way to rewrite this: $\sum_{k=0}^p {a_{ik}b_{kj}}$

Comment: Do you mean simply $a_{i0}b_{0j}+a_{i1}b_{1j}+\cdots+a_{ip}b_{pj}$?

Comment: No, with another formula.

Comment: Cf. [Einstein notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation)

Comment: @Victoria You can use the Inner product of  2 vectors as the hint of J. W. Tanner.

Comment: What about $\big( \begin{matrix} a_{i0} & a_{i1} & \cdots & a_{ip} \end{matrix} \big)
\begin{pmatrix} b_{0j} \\ b_{1j} \\ \vdots \\ b_{pj} \end{pmatrix}$?